# Pull Information from Webpage and Input into Cell

Tags: vba, excel

Instead of having this information show up as a message box, how can I modify the code so that that data is inputted into Sheet1.Range("A1")? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Demo()
With CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.realtytrac.com/property" & Sheet1.Range("J11"), False
    .setRequestHeader "DNT", "1"
    .Send
    MsgBox Split(Split(.responseText, "itemprop='propertyID'>")(1), "<")(0)
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Demo()
With CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.realtytrac.com/property" & Sheet1.Range("J11"), False
    .setRequestHeader "DNT", "1"
    .Send
    val = Split(Split(.responseText, "itemprop='propertyID'>")(1), "<")(0)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").value = val
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a compile error: Function Call on left-hand side of assignment must return variant or object. I'll look into what that means.

Comment: Fixed it dimming Val as String. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a valid response in your XMLHTTP object you should be able to use the following:

```
Sub Demo()
With CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.realtytrac.com/property" & Sheet1.Range("J11"), False
    .setRequestHeader "DNT", "1"
    .Send
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = Split(Split(.responseText, "itemprop='propertyID'>")(1), "<")(0)
End With
End Sub
```